# Best way to debug exception

Tags: android, ddms

any best way to debug exception unless using logcat since the overall code are very big? do u think using break point to view the value if installing apk into actual android phone and running it on the phone via usb cable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do u think using break point to view the value if installing apk into actual android phone

If this means, 'can you debug using breakpoints on the actual phone?'. The answer is Yes

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html) you can follow

Comment: any other best way to debug exception unless logcat & breakpoint?

Comment: Take a [look at this](http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/). I'm not sure what *extra* are you looking for?.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the codebase is mostly irrelevant when trying to find the cause of an exception (It might complicate things a little, but in general the procedure is the same as debugging a small application). Debugging is the most efficient way of finding bugs, because you're running directly inside your application and you will not have to speculate about the current state of your application (you can actually look at it).

I suggest that you...

- Get familiar with Eclipse debugging
- Read the stacktrace
- Try to find the exact line in the code where the exception happened (according to the stacktrace)
- Set a breakpoint at the exact line or at the beginning of the method
- Restart you application and wait until you hit the breakpoint
- Inspect the variables using the tools in Eclipse

Hope that helps.